# how to get links in UI through sitemap-generator in ruby on rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap

How to get links in UI through sitemap_generator Gem.
actually, i added the sitemap_generator gem in application and then it generated one xml file also.but, I am not getting the thing that how to generate the links in the web site of application?